# Pagination helpers outputting incorrect results - cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, pagination

I have a project model which has many Invoices and Credits. I'm trying to paginate both the Invoices and Credits info in a particular function in my ProjectsController.

No problems getting the correct info paginated:

```
App::Import('Model', 'Invoice');
$this->Invoice = new Invoice;
$this->Paginator->settings = array(
    'conditions' => array('Invoice.paid' => 1, 'Invoice.project_id'=>$id),
    'limit' => 5
);
$paidInvoices = $this->paginate('Invoice');

App::Import('Model', 'Credit');
$this->Credit = new Credit;
$this->Paginator->settings = array(
    'conditions' => array('Credit.project_id' => $id),
    'limit' => 3
);
$credits = $this->paginate('Credit');
```

The problem is that even though I specify the model like it says in the docs 6 page links will appear: there should only be 2. There will always be a next link even though there might be no page to visit.

```
echo '<div class="right pagination">'.$this->Paginator->first('<< first', array('model'=>'Credit')).
    $this->Paginator->prev('< ' . __('previous'), array('model'=>'Credit'), null, array('class' => 'prev disabled')).
    $this->Paginator->numbers(array('separator' => '', 'model'=>'Credit')).
    $this->Paginator->next(__('next', array('model'=>'Credit')) . ' >', array('model'=>'Credit'), null, array('class' => 'next disabled')).
    $this->Paginator->last('last >>', array('model'=>'Credit')).'</div>';
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like CakePHP is getting confused when calculating the number of available results. The `$settings` property seems like the culprit.

You have to include the key for you model name, as follows:

```
    $this->Paginator->settings['Invoice'] = array(
        'conditions' => array('Invoice.paid' => 1, 'Invoice.project_id'=>$id),
        'limit' => 5
    );
```

and

```
    $this->Paginator->settings['Credit'] = array(
        'conditions' => array('Credit.project_id' => $id),
        'limit' => 3
    );
```